# RStudio no longer works after reinstalling

Tags: r, rstudio

I tried reinstalling r and rstudio but now it no longer works and crashes when plotting pressure. It works in the console which leads me to believe something is wrong with rstudio when I reinstalled or deleted the previous rstudio app. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Check for a `.Rdata` file in the project directory and move it out of the way, then try again. (Likely the same for any `.Rproj` or whatever project-file might be left behind. It's possible that something in there is corrupting the R-reload process.

Comment: What exactly do you do that causes the crash? Is it just when you open the program? Is it when you run a specific bit of code? Is it any time you plot? What OS version, R version, and RStudio version are you running?